# Python post request not working

Tags: python, post, request

```
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
payload = {"q": "python"}

s = requests.session()
r = s.post(url, data=payload)
print r.text
```

I wish to use a post request in order to obtain the subsequent webpage. However, the above code prints the source code of the home page and not the the next page. Can someone tell me what I should do to obtain the source code of the next page? I have searched through many questions on StackOverflow related to this and haven't found a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "next page"? Does the page you're trying to send a POST request, redirects somewhere else after a POST request?

Comment: it will return response object until you specify content...

Comment: By next page I mean the page that would open if I had myself filled the form on a browser

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed how do I specify content?

Comment: if you're using framework for eg: if its django ,you will specify renderstring or redirect both will init HTML content

Comment: first of all tell which framework are you using?

Comment: This is not how you do a request to stackoverflow. Check this url out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=3&sort=newest&pagesize=50 it has a page=3 and a pagesize=50 but tagged/python so you need to include that in the starting url